# customize save method in views.py

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I have a table in my models file with 4 columns and I want to design it such that there is a limit to ten rows in the table. When the limit is exceeded the oldest row will be deleted.

I tried to customize the save() method as follows:

```
def insert_pos(request, lat, lon):
    current_user_id = request.user.id
    latlon = Maps(latitud = lat, longitud = lon, data_id = 1)

    def save(self):
        objects=Maps.objects.all()
        if objects.count() == 10:
            objects[0].delete()
        self.save()

    latlon.save()
    return HttpResponse ()
```

My database is not limited yet, sombody could help me please. I am new in Django

Comment: no this is wrong method .. I think `save` come in models file only ...

Comment: As @RajaSimon says, the `save` method should be in your model. Your `insert_pos` function, where does it live and when is called? You need to show us more code (model and view) in order to help you.

Comment: I have a python application that is inserting data into my database. I get the values in my view as lat and lon.

Answer (score 1):

In `models.py` file I extend the `save()` like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    objects=Maps.objects.all()
    if objects.count() == 11:
        objects[0].delete()
    super(Maps, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```